# Spectral graph theory: would "higher order" graph cuts make sense?

Tags: matrices, soft-question, representation-theory, spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory

The problem of performing [graph cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(graph_theory)) is well known and has many algorithms for many different applications. Is it a concept that is possible to extend or generalize in some sense? Can we find *second order* graph cuts in some sense?

Since [spectral graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_graph_theory) provides us the tools to make matrices for *distance*, *adjoint* and *laplacian* et.c. for a single graph, then for multiple graphs or even a family of graphs maybe we can try and find *simultaneous* graph cuts a little bit like we in [representation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) we can find a joint canonical basis where the canonical matrix is block-diagonal and corresponds to irreducible sub groups:

$${\bf M_i = TC_iT}^{-1} : {\bf C_i} \text{:s have the same block-diagonal structure } \forall {i}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only think of one example of "simultaneous cut".
It is known that we can get the spectral bisection of a graph from the Laplacian spectrum. A common heuristic is to partition the vertices of the graph based on the sign of the entries in the [Fiedler Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity#Fiedler_vector).

Let $ \mathbf{L}_{1},\mathbf{L}_2 $ be Laplacian matrices of two graphs $G_{1},G_{2}$ respectively.  If $$ \mathbf{L}_{1} \mathbf{L}_{2}= \mathbf{L}_{2} \mathbf{L}_{1}, $$ then the spectral bisection heuristic I mentioned above is going to partition the vertex sets in the exact same way.
If $ I_{1},I_{2} $ are the sets of vertex indices corresponding to the two partitions of $ G_{1} $ and the index sets $ I_{3},I_{4} $ for the two partitions of $ G_{2} $, then $I_{1}=I_{3} $ and $ I_{2} = I_{4} $.

That's because the commutativity of the Laplacian matrices guarantees a set of simultaneously diagonalizing eigenvectors, so the Fiedler vector is going to be the same.
I am not sure if that's what you're looking for though.